# What are all the reasons/possibilities that may fail to release disk space occupied by TEMPORARY table?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, database-size, temporary-tables

We're using PostgreSQL v8.2.3.  Ours is a web-based application and we're using pgpool-II v 2.0.1 purely for connection pooling (we
don't use other features of pgpool like Replication, Load Balancing, etc.).

Recently, in our Production server there was a drastic and unexpected growth in
database disk space.  In just 2 days, database size has grown from 6 GB to
14 GB.

I then ran the following query to find the size of the top 20 biggest
relation in the database:

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size" FROM pg_class
C LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace) WHERE nspname NOT IN
('pg_catalog') ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC LIMIT 20;
```

I didn't find any issues here.  Even I could say that the sum of
"total_size" of the above command is less than the size occupied by the
database itself.  I'm using the following command to find the size of
database:

```
select oid, datname, pg_database_size(datname) as actualsize,
pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) as size from pg_database order by
datname;
```

I also used to physically check the database size occupied using the following
command:

```
du -sh /usr/local/pgsql/data/base/2663326
```

I then physically listed the file size in descending order from the location
"*/usr/local/pgsql/data/base/2663326*".  Here, "2663326" is the OID of my
database.

```
[root@dbserver 2663326]# ll -lhS |head -15
total 14G
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  6 15:03 1508904
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:16 1924478.10
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:17 1924478.2
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:19 1924478.3
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:17 1924478.4
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:18 1924478.5
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:20 1924478.6
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:20 1924478.7
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:14 1924478.8
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1.0G Sep  2 21:19 1924478.9
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  876M Sep  6 15:02 1508614
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  615M Sep  6 15:03 1508904.1
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  531M Sep  2 21:20 1924478.11
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  235M Sep  6 15:02 1510463
```

Though these files are not human-readable, from whatever I was able to read
from the file, I found that the top 10 files created are related to a
particular complex application report.   In this complex report, we're
creating temporary table using `CREATE TEMP TABLE MY_TEMP_TABLE(col1, col2,
...)`, 5 columns in this temp table are indexed and it's being heavily used.
Though temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session,
I'm finding that the disk space occupied by these temporary tables are not
being freed-up.  As you can also see, some file names are numbered with
decimal places (`1924478.2, 1924478.3, etc.`) with a maximum file size of 1
GB.  Particularly, these type of files are related to this complex report
that makes use of temporary tables.

I can also confirm that my temporary tables are not getting listed from the
following query (which shows that as per system catalog tables, it's been dropped):

```
select pn.nspname, pc.relname, pc.relfilenode from pg_class pc, pg_namespace
pn where pc.relnamespace = pn.oid and pc.relname ilike 'my_temp_table';
```

**NOTE:** Auto vacuum daemon is already running in the server.  Even a manual
`VACUUM FULL ANALYZE`, followed by `REINDEX` command is not able to reclaim the
lost disk space.  Only when we exported and imported, the database size
comes back to the original 6 GB size.

So, based on my observations, it appears that at some point of time/context, for some *unknown reasons*, the disk
space occupied by the temporary table is not being released properly by PostgreSQL server.

What are all the reasons/possibilities that it may fail to free-up disk space
occupied by TEMPORARY table?   How do I fix/handle in this situation?

Comment: Is there a good reason you're running a version of PostgreSQL that's missing 4 YEARS of updates?  Note that it's entirely possible you're suffering from a bug here when it comes to reclaiming space from a temp table.  Either way, please update to pg 8.2.22 now, and start planning to upgrade to a version that's still receiving support soon.

Answer (score 3):

In more recent versions of Postgres (I think since 8.3) you can assign a special tablespace for temporary tables which might help you. This is documented here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TEMP-TABLESPACES

Given the fact that 8.2 will be de-supported at the end of the year it might be a good idea to upgrade. There have been numerous enhancements to VACUUM and the handling of temporary files since 8.2 so you might benefit from those.

**Edit:**
The reason why I think this (separate tablespace) could help you, is that you can simply drop and recreate the tablespace (files) to reclaim the spaces occupied.

But then I'd assume that due to all the improvements that were implemented in the last 5 years the current version might release the space without any further action from your side (especially because VACUUM FULL has been completely rewritten in 9.0)

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html does say that disk space is freed.

Comment: Hmm, I only saw the "*However, it will not return the space to the operating system*" sentence. But apparently that's not true for vacuum full. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `In more recent versions of Postgres (I think since 8.3) you can assign a special tablespace for temporary tables` - Can you point me to the exact documentation link/resource on this feature?

Comment: @Gnanam: See my edit

Comment: +1 but postgres support is sometimes available from a distro after it ceases from postgres - RHEL is a case in point

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: How can assigning a special tablespace for temporary tables can help me in this specific case (that is how do I find/track in which situation the disk space occupied by temporary tables is *not being released* properly to operating system)? Can you please make me understand/clear on how it can help?